# Attempting to add a button but getting "[object HTMLInputElement]" instead of the button

Tags: javascript, button

I'm trying to build buttons dynamically in a for loop where each iteration builds a button. I've done this before no problem and copied this code from an old project. Now I get **[object HTMLInputElement]** posted to the DOM instead of my button.

Any advice? Thanks.

What I have so far:

```
var element = document.createElement("input");
element.className = 'appointmentClass'
element.id = countAppointments;
element.type = 'button';
element.name = 'name';
element.value = 'remove';
element.onclick = function () {
        alert('removed appointment '+ this.id)
//      addShow(this.id);
};
```

Comment: So how are you adding the element to the page? That is the bug...

Comment: How are you adding the node to the DOM? This code only creates a node but doesn't render it.

Comment: Sorry for forgetting this guys, I'm appending as such:     

tableRow.append("<td>" + element + "</td>"); which appends the object data listed above appended to the DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
tableRow.append("<td>" + element + "</td>");
```

You are causing the browser engine to call toString() on the DOM node which results in what you are seeing. You need to create a td element and append the button to the TD element. and than append the td to the tr.

pure JS

```
var td = document.createElement("td");
td.appendChild(element);
tableRow.appendChild(td);  //or     tableRow.append(td);
```

or with jQuery

```
var td = $("<td></td>");
td.append(element);
tableRow.append("td");
```

Answer (score 1):

you just need to append the button to the body using `parentElement.appendChild(element)`

```js
var 
  element = document.createElement("input");
element.className = 'appointmentClass'
element.id = 'countAppointments';
element.type = 'button';
element.name = 'name';
element.value = 'remove';
element.onclick = function (){
  alert('removed appointment '+ this.id)
  //  addShow(this.id);
}

document.body.appendChild( element );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not appending `DOM element` anywhere. You can use `parentNode.appendChild` method which accepts argument as a `node`

Try this:

```js
var parent = document.getElementById('conteiner');
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var
    element = document.createElement("input");
  element.className = 'appointmentClass'
  element.id = 'countAppointments' + i;
  element.type = 'button';
  element.name = 'name';
  element.value = 'remove';
  element.onclick = function() {
    alert(this.id);
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
  };
  parent.appendChild(element);
}
```

```html
<div id="conteiner"></div>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/oesox7px/)

Answer (score -1):

you can try Jquery append method like:

```js
$(".container").append("<input type="button" value="XXXX" name="XXXX" id="XXXXX">");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm using jquery to append actually,   $('#apptable').append(tableRow); tableRow.append("<td>" + element + "</td>");

Answer (score -2):

It turns out I can't append with  for this input element. Removing this and just appending 'element' as I was previously works.

Comment: There is no way you can not append `input` element. Check the console for errors. In provided code `countAppointments` is undefined..

Comment: This should be a comment.