# obJect Object showing instead of button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that I am building via js, and it this table the rows ar being populated from a jquery modal dialog upon closing, the data displays on each row, but what I want also is a button to display in each row for further processing is need be.

When I add the button to the column it shows [object Object] instead of the button. I have looked at a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647170/attempting-to-add-a-button-but-getting-object-htmlinputelement-instead-of-thhttp://) and getting nothing in the column. I am quite knew to JS and could use some assistance The code is below. I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
$(function () {
var dialog, form,

skuNumber = $("#skuNumber");
productName = $("#productName");
description = $("#description");
quantity = $("#quantity");
border = $("#border");
inkColor = $("#inkColor");
allFields = $([]).add(skuNumber).add(productName).add(description).add(quantity).add(border).add(inkColor);
tips = $(".validateTips");

function addItem() {
    var remove = $('<input type="button" id="remove" value="remove" style="width:80px" class="btn btn-danger" />');
    var td = $("<td></td>");
    td.append(remove);
    var valid = true;

    allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");

    if (valid) {
        $("#myTest tbody").append("<tr>" +
          "<td>" + skuNumber.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + productName.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + description.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + quantity.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + border.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + inkColor.val() + "</td>" +
          "td" +
          "</tr>");
          dialog.dialog("close");     

    }
    return valid;
}

dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({

    autoOpen: false,
    height: 550,
    width: 650,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Add A Line Item": addItem,
        Cancel: function () {
            dialog.dialog("close");
        }
    },
    close: function () {
        form[0].reset();
        allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
    }
});

form = dialog.find("form").on("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    addItem();
});

$("#add").button().on("click", function () {
    dialog.dialog("open");
});
```

I am appending the td to this table below, I have the td's commented out in code

```
<table id="myTest" class="table table-responsive">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sku Number</td>
                    <td>Product Name</td>
                    <td>Description</td>
                    <td>Quantity</td>
                    <td>Border</td>
                    <td>Ink Color</td>
                    <td>Action</td>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        @*<td>Test</td>
                        <td>Test</td>
                        <td>Test</td>
                        <td>Test</td>
                        <td>Test</td>
                        <td>Test</td>
                        <td><input type="button" id="remove" value="remove" style="width:80px" class="btn btn-danger" /></td>*@
                    </tr>
                </tbody>                
            </table>
```

Comment: Where are you appending td too?

Comment: PI I just included the table the td's are suppose to get appended to

Comment: I thinking it is suppose to get appended to the end of each row

Comment: Is it just the remove button that isn't appending correctly, or do you have problems with the other td's you're appending also?

Comment: just the remove button

Comment: Also, is that a typo? You have "<td>" + inkColor.val() + "</td>" + "td" + "</tr>". Shouldn't the lone "td" reference the variable td and not the string?

Comment: can't see where are you appending the button to the table. Did you post all your code?

Comment: I don't know why you are storing the button within the variable? Can't you just add it to the string concat like you do with the rest of the td's?

Comment: PI I was following another example, when I ran into the problem, with someone having a somewhat similiar situation, but I do appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just append the td var to the table:

```
   $('#myTest> tbody tr:last').append(td);
```

Exmaple here:
https://jsfiddle.net/00q44gyf/

Comment: Thanks Jaime that did it, always shyed away from javascript and jquery but I really need it now, I need to brush up on the language